# How to save "title" attribute of "a" with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I save the value of the title for a row? These are the values of the `title=%s:`

```
<a class="false" title=1106 href="/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false"><span class="small">(hide)</span></a>

<a class="false" title=1153 href="/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false"><span class="small">(hide)</span></a>

<a class="false" title=1175 href="/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false"><span class="small">(hide)</span></a>
```

...

I've tried countless variations but none of them work. This is what I have now:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("ready");

    $("a.false").click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest("tr.hide").hide("slow");
        var main_id = a.title;
        var display = "false";
        e.preventDefault();

    });

    $("a.false").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false",
            data: {main_id: "main_id", display: "display"},
            success: function(data) {
            display_false()
            alert("4 - returned");
            }

        });

    });
});
</script>
```

This is the third question on this topic. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: The values for your `title` attributes really ought to be in quotes

Comment: @ Clive: As others mentioned `var main_id = this.title;` works, giving the value of the title.

Comment: I meant in your HTML code :-) `title=1106` should be `title="1106"`. It's just good practice

Comment: Ok, thanks, fixed. For some reason I thought I did not need to put quotes when I was using string formatting with `%s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is pass the value of the `title` attribute along in your AJAX request. If that's the case, the easiest thing to do will be to do it all in one event handler (is there a reason you're binding 2 different handlers to the same event?):

```
$("a.false").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest("tr.hide").hide("slow");
    var main_id = this.title;
    var display = "false";
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/useradminpage",
        data: {main_id: main_id, display: display},
        success: function(data) {
            display_false();
            alert("4 - returned");
        }

    });
});
```

Your problem currently is that `main_id` and `display` are not in the scope of the second event listener, so will be undefined (and they shouldn't be quoted, otherwise you're just passing in strings). As you're passing in a `data` object to the `ajax` function, you don't really need to add the query string to the URL either.

Aside from that, when you assign a value to `main_id`, you're using `a.title`. In this case  `a` is undefined, and you will need to use `this`, which will be a reference to the clicked element.

Comment: @ James Allardice: Thanks! This looks beautiful and it works great and thanks for the detailed explanation. Can you clarify one more thing? I thought mistakenly that I needed to call the function that updated the database in `success:` that's why I have `display_false();` in there. But that line gives a `Uncaught ReferenceError: display_false is not defined` and when I comment out that line database is still updated. So what do I need to put inside `success:`? Documentation says "A function to be called if the request succeeds" so that confuses me. Thanks again.

Comment: I think what you've done is tried to call a PHP function from the JavaScript inside the `success` callback. That's never going to work, because PHP executes on the server, and JS on the client side. The `success` callback is simply a function that runs when the AJAX call finishes execution. You could, for example, use it to display a "success" message to the user.

Answer (score 5):

instead of

```
    var main_id = a.title;
```

try

```
    var main_id = $(this).attr('title');
```

because if I'm not wrong, "a" isn't defined

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that I might be missing something, but I suspect that your problem is using `a.title` instead of `this.title`:

```
$("a.false").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest("tr.hide").hide("slow");
    var main_id = this.title; // or you could use the jQuery object approach: $(this).attr('title') instead
    var display = "false";
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem in your original approach is that `a` would be parsed as a variable, which hasn't been assigned a value, nor has it been declared, so that it would return `undefined` or `null` (at best). Within the scope of the `each()` method, you're iterating over individual nodes; so to access the properties/attributes of that node use `this`.

Comment: @ David Thomas: Thanks. Yes, I was getting a undefined error in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

To access any attribute of a DOM element through jQuery, you can use the [.attr() function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
In your particular case you would do.

```
var main_id = $(this).attr('title');
```